# Removing last comma in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query which looks like this:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.TitleId) as Row, 
T.TitleId as TitleID, 
T.TitleSort as TitleName, 
TT.Description as TitleType, 
TS.Description as TitleOrigin,
--get genres
(select Genre.Description + ', ' from Genre where GenreId IN
(Select GenreId from TitleGenre WHERE TitleId = T.TitleId)
group by Genre.Description for xml path('')) AS Genres, ....
```

This code works, but I can't find a way to get rid of the last comma. This is how the returned row looks:

```
Action, Drama, Romance,
```

I need to get rid of last comma without using a function or declaring a variable, right here in the query. Is that possible? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Assuming the above is in a function called GetGenere why not just use left(getGenere,len(getGenere)-1)?

Comment: "I need to get rid of last comma without using a function or declaring a variable," -- For functions, assuming you mean user-defined functions, I can see the point (it requires DB permissions you might not have), but for what reason can variables and/or built-in functions not be used?

Comment: On an unrelated note, when using `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate rows it is a good idea to use `TYPE` and `.value` to get the string to avoid escaping certain characters. i.e `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use the following which uses `Left()` and `Len()`:

```
select *,
  left(Genres, len(Genres)-1) as Genres
from 
(
  SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.TitleId) as Row, 
  T.TitleId as TitleID, 
  T.TitleSort as TitleName, 
  TT.Description as TitleType, 
  TS.Description as TitleOrigin,
  --get genres
  (select Genre.Description + ', ' from Genre where GenreId IN
  (Select GenreId from TitleGenre WHERE TitleId = T.TitleId)
  group by Genre.Description for xml path('')) AS Genres, ....
) src
```

Comment: This uses a function. I have no idea why functions cannot be used, but the question says they cannot.

Comment: @hvd I am guessing that when they say function, then mean user-defined functions.

Comment: I initially thought so too, but given the restriction on variables (which clearly does not make sense, there is no technical argument against those), I have my doubts now.

Comment: @hvd if they cannot use a function, then they also cannot use `STUFF` which would make this incredibly difficult

Comment: Given the use of the `ROW_NUMBER` function in the question I think it is safe to say it only referred to UDFs

Comment: @GarethD that was my thought too

Comment: @GarethD Fair point. In that case, both this answer and sgeddes's look good to me.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should be close -- basically move the comma to the beginning and then remove it with STUFF:

```
STUFF(
        (
        select ', ' + Genre.Description from Genre where GenreId IN
(Select GenreId from TitleGenre WHERE TitleId = T.TitleId)
group by Genre.Description for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like below using window functions to optionally insert a comma.

```
SELECT
c.Name +
CASE WHEN 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name ORDER BY c.Name DESC)  
<>
COUNT(t.name) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name)   then ',' else '' END

FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
on t.Object_id = c.Object_id

FOR XML PATH('')
```

Basically add a comma unless it's the last record of the result set.